# get ASCII value of a Regex backreference in VBA

Tags: regex, vba, ascii

I have the following snippet in VBA

```
Dim RegEx As Object
Dim myResult As String

Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "([^a-z|A-Z|0-9|\s])"
End With

myResult = "Hello, World!"
```

I want to replace each regex match with its ascii value -- in this case, replace anything that's not a letter or number with its ascii value, so the resulting string should be

```
"Hello44 World33"
```

I basically want something like this to use the Asc() function on a backreference:

```
myResult = RegEx.Replace(myResult, Asc("$1"))
```

except that's not valid. I've tried escaping in various ways but I think I am barking up the wrong tree.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you can do it in one go with Replace(), but you can use Execute() and loop through the matches.  Note your original pattern also matched |, which I don't think you wanted.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim RegEx As Object, matches As Object, match As Object
    Dim myResult As String

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RegEx
     .Global = True
     .IgnoreCase = True
     .MultiLine = True
     .Pattern = "([^a-z0-9\s])"
    End With

    myResult = "Hello, World!"

    Set matches = RegEx.Execute(myResult)
    For Each match In matches
        Debug.Print "<" & match.Value & "> = " & Asc(match.Value)
        myResult = Replace(myResult, match.Value, Asc(match.Value))
    Next match
    Debug.Print myResult

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, Tim, thank you! Btw, I was using the pipe as an "or" separator, but I guess it's not called for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One of the signatures of Regex.Replace takes an evaluator instead of a string for the replacement value. Take a look at this:

[Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx#Y900)

Let me know if you need further help.

---

**Edit:** Added the actual code.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module RegExSample

    Function AscText(ByVal m As Match) As String
        Return Asc(m.ToString())
    End Function

    Sub Tester()
        Dim RegEx As Object, matches As Object, match As Object
        Dim myResult As String

        Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With RegEx
         .Global = True
         .IgnoreCase = True
         .MultiLine = True
         .Pattern = "([^a-z0-9\s])"
        End With

        myResult = "Hello, World!"

        myResult = RegEx.Replace(text, AddressOf RegExSample.AscText)
        Debug.Print myResult

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Looks good, but a little more verbose than Tim's response below. Thanks, though!

Comment: @MisterCoffee - I've added actual code. Code simplicity wise, I think they're similar.